# Getting data from multiple tables with MysqlReader

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

This is probably and easy question, but I lack understanding of SQL, and cant seem to find my answer elsewhere.
I have an existing solution which works fine when getting data from a single table, but when getting from two tables, when both contains the same row name, my problem occurs. 
This is what I have:

```
string Query="SELECT * FROM `Teams`,`Locations` WHERE Teams.LocationId=Locations.LocationId;";
OpenConnection();
MySqlCommand MysqlCommand=new MySqlCommand(Query,MysqlConnection);
MysqlReader=MysqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (MysqlReader.Read()) {
  ...
  Team.Size=MysqlReader["Size"].ToString();
  Location.Address=MysqlReader["Address"].ToString();
  Team.Name=MysqlReader["Name"].ToString();
  Location.Name=MysqlReader["Name"].ToString();
  ...
}
```

The Size and address I can easily fetch because the two tables dont share that row name. But both the Team and Location table has a Row called Name, but I only get the Team tables Name. How do I get the Locations Name when extracting data this way?

I dont know if this is a bad way of getting data from a SQL server, or if I should use JOIN instead, but so far this has been working fine for me.

Thanks alot.

Comment: "or if I should use JOIN instead" - you're using join already. This is just another syntax variant of inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can soleve this using Column Alias...Give Differentr Name to your Column as Alias in your selecr...Like Below

```
string Query="SELECT Teams.Name as TeamName,Locations.Name as LocationsName,Address ,Address FROM `Teams`,`Locations` WHERE Teams.LocationId=Locations.LocationId;";
OpenConnection();
MySqlCommand MysqlCommand=new MySqlCommand(Query,MysqlConnection);
MysqlReader=MysqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (MysqlReader.Read()) {
  ...
  Team.Size=MysqlReader["Size"].ToString();
  Location.Address=MysqlReader["Address"].ToString();
  Team.Name=MysqlReader["TeamName"].ToString();
  Location.Name=MysqlReader["LocationsName "].ToString();
  ...
}
```